# Accessing java member variable that has the name "type"

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

I am using a java library in which a class has a member named "type". If I do something like this:

```
class MyClass{
  public MyClass(){
    type = 5;
  }
  public int type;
}
```

then the java compiler compiles it fine. But if I try to access it from scala:

```
val x = new MyClass()
x.type = 10
```

I get this message:

> identifier expected but 'type' found.

How do I work around this issue?

I am guessing this has come up before but I could not find a related question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this in scala by using backticks:

```
x.`type` = 10
```

Any string enclosed in backticks can be used as an identifier, or to access one.

Comment: ... which enables you to write fun things like `def \`(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻\` = { throw new RuntimeException }`